# How to redirect to the "current page" in oauth 2.0?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, authorization

If I understand oauth (authorization code grant, ignoring pcke for now) correctly the structure works a bit like this (as explained [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/authorization/the-authorization-request/)):

client redirects to something like:

```
https://authorization-server.com/auth?response_type=code
&client_id=29352735982374239857
&redirect_uri=https://example-app.com/callback
&scope=create+delete
&state=xcoivjuywkdkhvusuye3kch
```

Which then shows an authentication page and handles this (simple username+password form).

After the user has been authenticated the oauth server sends another redirect to the client browser. However this time to `https://example-app.com/callback` with as parameter the authorization code. So far so good. However upon reading the explanation in the url above I notice this:

> The redirect_uri is not required by the spec, but your service should
> require it. This URL must match one of the URLs the developer
> registered when creating the application, and the authorization server
> should reject the request if it does not match.

It tells me that the URL needs to be registered - which implies to me that there can only be a few "callback urls".

This then confuses me and makes me question the usage: in our application one *needs* be able to log in at any point. And it is really confusing/terrible user experience if after logging in the user is returned to a landing page. - An example is a user who is ordering something and can log in just before the payment is completed.

Is the only way to encode the actual url in the "state" variable? That seems cumbersome and prone to problems. (let alone having to make an encode function etc). Or are there other ways this can be done that I am not aware of?

--

I noticed in the naswer given that some more details are important. Our web application runs as a "semi"  single page application. However due to security concerns an extra backend-for-frontend server is added to the mix, which handles the oauth codeflow. This was on advice given in a [previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75800924/in-oauth2-how-to-share-the-access-key-with-the-main-webapp).

Comment: In an SPA you typically write code to save application state before the redirect, then restore it after,. This is different to the OAuth state parameter, as Quentin indicates. See [this example code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L106), which saves to session storage. This also provides a deep linking capability, if users can bookmark your URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback URL is the URL responsible for accepting the OAuth token from the third party OAuth provider, processing it, and then presenting the user with whatever you want to present them with after they login.

Whatever you want to present them with can be a redirect to another page on your site.

> Is the only way to encode the actual url in the "state" variable?

The state parameter is designed to hold an anti-CSRF token. You shouldn't encode other data there.

Store the URL you want to redirect back to elsewhere, such as in a server-side session.

Comment: but that wouldn't work with a single page application. The server is never informed where the user is at each moment in time.

Comment: I said "such as". Use sessionStorage or something instead.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it has put me on the right track to a solution. Though I felt a bit weird since it didn't really answer my question directly: "Or are there other ways this can be done that I am not aware of?". (At least it only provided a vague answer "such as...").